# Class files on classpath not found or not accessible

Tags: eclipse, bukkit

After working on a project for around a week it suddenly stopped exporting. Every time I try to export my project I just get an error.  Nothing is wrong with my classes what so ever.

```
     JAR creation failed. See details for additional information.
     Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for: 
     'TroubleInTT/src/me/infernoartz/timv/Main.java'
     Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for: 
     'TroubleInTT/src/me/infernoartz/timv/GameState.java'
     Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for: 
     'TroubleInTT/src/me/infernoartz/timv/commands/RoleCommand.java'
     Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for: 
     'TroubleInTT/src/me/infernoartz/timv/commands/TimvCommand.java'
     Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for: 
     'TroubleInTT/src/me/infernoartz/timv/events/PlayerInteractEvent.java'

     And so it continues down..
```

Comment: can you show us your classpath? should be in the file `.classpath` in eclipse

Comment: Where excactly?

Comment: Sorry I was busy. The file should be directly in your project root folder, or press CTRL+SHIFT+R in eclipse and enter `.classpath`. Alternatively right-click on an eclipse project and select Properties, select the Java Build Path link on the left. Then select the Source Tab. You'll see a list of all the java source folders.

Comment: https://hastebin.com/wiwiyohime.xml Here is the .classpath

Comment: so you have your local "src" folder in the classpath that is good, I'm not so familiar with bukkit libs but why do you have linked two of them, also in different user directories that can't be good. "C:/Users/Jorgenerkul/Downloads/craftbukkit-1.8.8.jar" and "C:/Users/Håvard-PC/Desktop/jarfiles/SPIGOTAPI/craftbuk??kit-1.8.8.jar", do you need them both? Also I suggest putting the libs in your project inside a "libs" folder or something, not somewhere on the desktop :)

Comment: Oh, I shared the project with a friend and he had to add a Jar file to it. Maybe that is the issue.

Comment: good I guess it's solved, another reason why you should put your libs inside the project folder with relative paths, then you never had a problem like this in the first place :)

Answer (score 1):

Yup! as @xander posted a friend of mine had imported a .jar file into the project. I just had to remove it from .classpath, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to give '-classpath=""'??

Comment: What do you mean?